# Error :failed to find target with hash string 'android-23'

Tags: android, gradle, sdk

Error happened after i tried to change compile and target sdk from 22 to 23.
Tried to move back to 22 but same error message will appear with 'android-22' instead.

Changed SDK path, confirm SDK platforms are installed, tried to clear gradle cache, tried re-installing android studio.

Nothing works, someone please help.

Edit 1 - Just tried with another project and no error message came out. Means Android studio and SDK doesn't have a problem. Problem lies within project.

Comment: You say that problem lies within project, so can you show your gradle? Did you try cleaning project and rebuild it? Did you try FIle -> Invalidate cache / restart ?

Comment: add your `build.gradle` file of this problematic project

Comment: @DamianKozlak cannot clean and rebuild as gradle cannot be synced. Tried to invalidate cache/ restart (clear cache of android studio) as well as clearing cache of gradle. I've solved my problem with my answer below. Thanks for both of your help. piotrek1543

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to revive my project by doing the following.

Remove all dependencies in module level gradles. Leave the default bare minimum settings in your root project gradle. Sync it. Slowly add back the dependencies.

Although IDE error mentioned 'android-23' which will lead one to think it's a sdk problem. But i believe this is actually due to using appcompat 23 with sdk 22. I have no evidence of this but there are other problems that can be searched with how appcompat version should match sdk.

Comment: `using appcompat 23 with sdk 22` - yeah, and this might be the problem, which you didn't mention in question